# Is there an API that has a basic maintenance schedule for a vehicle?

Tags: json, api-design

I am working on a side project and was looking to see if there are any API's that given a vehicle's year, make, and model, it would show sort of a timeline for that vehicle's maintenance. For example, how often to change oil, when to change transmission fluid, etc.

Does anyone know of any API's that have this sort of information? I was going to end up trying to create a basic timeline that works with every car, but I thought it would be better to be more accurate with the chosen vehicle model.

Comment: I am curious if you found any API which fit your needs. I am looking for exactly that in my project.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)